# Interpolate between indexes in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames, one contains a force-time curve, the other a force-position curve e.g.:

```
load = pandas.DataFrame()
load["time"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
load["force"] = np.log10(load["time"])
```

and

```
pos = pd.DataFrame()
pos["x"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
pos["y"] = [5,4,3,2,1]
pos["z"] = [0,0,1,2,2]
pos.index = [-.7, -.1, 0, .1, .5]
```

now for each force value i want to have the corresponding x,y,z value from the second table, so a table with time as index and x, y and z as values.

the resulting table should look like this (I calculate the first three rows by hand):

```
res["x"] = [3, 4.5025, 4.9428, ...]
res["y"] = [3, 1.4974, 1.0571, ...]
res["z"] = [1, 2.0000, 2.0000, ...]
res.index = [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

my manual calculation uses the following procedure:

searching for values f1, f2, p1 and p2 (force and position values from load table bevore and after force at time i and then perform an linear interpolation between these point, e.g.:

```
p_interpolate = p_before + (f - f_before) / (f_after - f_before) * (p_after - p_before)
```

I have looked at the DataFrame.Interpolate() command, but it can only fill empty values of a DataFrame as far as I understand it.

The force-time-curve is much longer (>100000 values) than the force-position-curve (about 3-9 values)

Comment: show us your expected output

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: how your result should looks like